# Fine tuning of an informative replacement for rm

Tags: file-system, bash, console

I want to replace `rm` by a more informative variant: I would like to see which files will be deleted, along with their size, and I would like this information to use the same coloring as ls. As an example (please imagine the coloring):

```
# remove -r foo/ bar/*
4K   bar/file1
1.2M foo/
6.1M bar/file2
remove -r 3 files, 7.3M [yn]? _
```

I built on suggestions found in [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/605414/how-to-merge-ls-commands-colors-with-the-output-of-find-or-du), and now have a bash script that I begin to like. I have been using it for a few days without noticing any obvious errors. However, I would appreciate any help with making sure that the script will not misbehave in cases I did not foresee.

Here is my code for the coloring:

```
du_colored (){
    # read ls --color output into ls_colored_array
    # use \13 as a trick to handle names with spaces 
    read -d '\n' -r -a ls_colored_array <<< $(ls -Ad --color "$@" | tr " " "\13")

    if [[ ${#ls_colored_array[@]} = 0 ]]; then return 1; fi

    # - loop over the array and issue du -sh for every element (without coloring)
    # - exchange du's ouput with ls's
    # - finally sort the output
    for i in "${ls_colored_array[@]}"; do
        i=`echo $i | tr "\13" " "`
        printf '%s' "${i}" | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" | \
            xargs -n1 -0 du -sh | awk -v i="$i" '{ printf "%-4s ", $1; print i }'
    done | sort -h
}
```

and the removal script:

```
# Separate options to rm from 'real' arguments
for i in "$@"; do
    case $i in
        -*) options+=( "$i" ) ;;
        *)  toRemove+=( "$i" ) ;;
    esac
done

# Print file list
# Abort if no files match
du_colored "${toRemove[@]}"
if [ "_$?" != "_0" ]; then exit 1; fi

# Print summary
count=$(find "${toRemove[@]}" 2>/dev/null | wc -l 2>/dev/null)
size=$(du -sch "${toRemove[@]}" 2>/dev/null | tail -1 | tr '\t' ' ')
plural="s"
if [ $count -eq 1 ]; then plural=""; fi
printf "remove ${options[@]} ($count file$plural, $size) [ny]? " ; read
if [ "_$REPLY" = "_y" ]; then
    /bin/rm ${options[@]} ${toRemove[@]}
else
    echo '(cancelled)'
fi
```

- Does this look safe in the sense that what `du_colored` presents is exactly what will be deleted? Both files and directories seem to be treated correctly, even if they include spaces or wildcards. Are there scenarios that I missed? An obvious one are file names that contain a `\13` character.
- The initial `ls` in `du_colored` throws errors for non-existing files, which I like because it mimicks the behavior of regular `rm`. However, I currently discard all error messages of the final `find` and `grep` commands, such that non-existing files do not produce multiple errors. This seems like a dirty trick. Is there a cleaner way?
- Bonus question: Is there an easy way to make the output use multiple columns, just as a regular `ls` would? I tried several ways to pipe the output of `du_colored` to other tools, but either the colors were lost completely or the control characters for the coloring broke the alignment, as they do in `ls --color | pr -2 -t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bonus question: Does `ls -C` help?

```
-C     list entries by columns
```

You need `-r` to remove directories, so do you intend to impose this check as well when directories are specified?

```
plural="s"
if [ $count -eq 1 ]; then plural=""; fi
```

That can be rewritten as

```
[ $count -eq 1 ] && plural="" || plural="s"
```

Is the use of `_` really necessary here?

```
if [ "_$?" != "_0" ]; then exit 1; fi
if [ "_$REPLY" = "_y" ]; then
```

**edit**: Bonus question, round 2...

You could try this for `du_colored`:

```
du_colored() {
    du -sh "$@" | awk -F'\t' -v COL=4 \
        '{if(++c>COL){c=1;print""}("ls -Ad --color \""$2"\"")|getline entry;
        printf "%6s %s\t",$1,entry}END{print""}' | \
    column -s $'\t' -t
}
```

Instead of parsing `ls` output carefully to feed into `du`, I started from the output of `du` and then [replacing each entry](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe) with its `ls --Ad --color` output. `COL` is used to fix the number of 'columns' we want `column` to pick up afterwards, which is in turn used to print the appropriate newlines.

Finally, I feed the output to `column` as a final attempt at pretty-printing. `\t` is used as the delimiter throughout.

It still doesn't look as nice as the default non-piped `ls` output, but at least it's something I suppose...

**edit 2**: Bonus question, round 3...

I hope this is what's required... :)

```
du_colored() {
    awk -F'/' 'NR==FNR{k=$0;gsub(/\x1B\[[;[:digit:]]*m/,"",k);s[k]=$0}
        NR!=FNR{l=$0;for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=2){v=$i;gsub(/[ ]+$/,"",v);sub(v,s[v],l)};
            gsub("/"," ",l);print l}' \
    <(ls -Ad --color "$@") \
    <(du -sh "$@" | awk -F'\t' -v C=4 '{if(++c>C){c=1;print""}printf "/%6s/%s\t",$1,$2}
        END{print""}' | column -s $'\t' -t)
}
```

1. Get both the output of `ls -Ad --color "$*"` and `du -sh "$@" ...` using [`bash` process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) to pass into `awk`.

   - The `du -sh` command is in turn piped to an 'internal' `awk` command, similar to my earlier suggestion, for `column` to render properly. What's crucial to note here is that the start, the size and the file/directory entry are delimited using the `/` character, which is the *safest delimiter* as files <s>and directories</s> cannot have that (nested directories yes though).
2. The 'main' `awk` command uses `/` to split each line into 1 + `C` * 2 columns (`C=4` used above). By using the combination of `NR==FNR`/`NR!=FNR` conditions, we can specify different handling for the two 'files'.

   - For the `ls` output, i.e. `NR==FNR`, we construct a map from the file/directory (by stripping away the color codes - `gsub(/\x1B\[[;[:digit:]]*m/,"",k)`) to its colored output.
   - For the `du` output, we then substitute the file/directory *in the appropriate fields* (after trimming the extra spaces behind - `gsub(/[ ]+$/,"",v)`) with the colored output from the mapping.
   - After substituting each `/` character back to a  character, we reprint the entire line, which now contains the colored output.

This is arguably more efficient as both `ls` and `du` are performed once on the arguments. The lesson learned here is that `column` doesn't play ball with most control characters (seemingly `\t` is the only exception here). For some reason, `sort`-ing on `du`'s output is still introducing minor quirks in my own testing, so I'm leaving that out for now.

Comment: `ls -C` was also my first instinct, but I do not think that it helps in the current setup: I use ls only to populate the file list. The coloring and size information is then provided by `du_colored` on each item of the list. This formatted output is what I would like to print in multiple columns.

Comment: The second solution to the bonus question is quite elegant and probably also way more portable than mine, thanks a lot!
My `column` still hickups on the varying number of coloring escape codes used for different file types, misaligning the entries slightly. Is this a known bug and/or something that is easy to fix?

Comment: @klimpergeist seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151601/color-escape-codes-in-pretty-printed-columns

Comment: Maybe all we need is to `column` first...

Comment: Indeed. Here is a version with column first. Only works if `column` has a way to access the terminal width. `du_colored() {
    du -sh "$@" | sort -h | column | sed -e 's_\(\t\t*\)_\v\1\v_g' | awk -F'\v' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=4){ ("ls -Ad --color \""$(i+2)"\"")|getline entry;
            printf "%6s%s%s%s",$(i),$(i+1),entry,$(i+3)}; print ""}'
}
`

Comment: The version from edit2 does not work for me. `column` complains about an overlong line. I fixed that by appending `END {print ""}` to `du`'s `awk`, but now the part following `NR!=FNR` is not executed any more. I'll try later to solve this. If I can't, I might just stick with the version from my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Does this cause problems for utilities calling `rm`?

If so, this:

```
if [ -t 1 ] ; then ..your code..; fi
```

will make sure you don't send unwanted output to programs using `rm`.
This solution only works for POSIX-compatible shells.

[See this and other answers for more info on detecting whether you are in a shell or not.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/911213/2531091)

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding because the question was migrated from Unix to Code Review. @NicolaiS this answer style doesn't fit the CR model well, probably best to delete it. Sorry about the mix-up.

Comment: It is alright to post answers pointing out bugs.

Comment: It would be better to explain this in more detail in your answer, however.  Feel free to drop by chat to discuss this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor

Comment: Interesting information, but irrelevant to this code, since the entire point of the program is to display information to the terminal.

Comment: I would not even want to replace `rm`: Once you work on another system, bad things will happen. Instead, I called my script `rem` and added an alias to my bashrc: `alias rm='echo "Refusing to delete! Use \"rem\"!" || '`